# Closing a modal box reloads the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, so I have this weird issue on my website which I might have a hard time explaining. I am working on a website which only has one page(index.html) and no scroll. I have a navbar on the left with some menu items. So when clicked on a menu item a box appears with content. As it is a single page no scroll website, I have used IDs to call those boxes. Please see the code below:

```
<div class="nav-content">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

when clicked on a menu item this kind of section appears on the screen.

```
<section class="content show background-overlay" id="about">
    <div class="aboutUs">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
        <div class="overflow-scroll">
            Lorem ipsumasfasfasfasfafafsafs         
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And the browser address bar shows something like this after clicking on the links:
file:///C:/Users/zak/Desktop/web/project1/index.html#home 
or 
file:///C:/Users/zak/Desktop/web/project1/index.html#gallery

Now I have used a modal box inside the gallery content section and after I close the modal box, the page does not stay at the gallery content section but reloads.

For example:

Modal box is here: 
file:///C:/Users/zak/Desktop/web/project1/index.html#gallery

After modal is closed: 
file:///C:/Users/zak/Desktop/web/project1/index.html (which is the home content section)

I want the gallery section to stay open even if I close the modal.

For the modal, I have not used any JS or jQuery. It is pure HTML and CSS. To get rid of the issue I have tried a simple jquery code:

```
$('#modal_close').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

This code just stops everything working.

Can anybody tell me how to stop the page from reloading after the modal box is closed?

Comment: Where is your modal with `#modal_close`

Comment: Where is your close button/anchor with `#modal_close`?

Comment: Most likely, you have a button `<button>` or `<button type='submit'>` (no `type=` defaults to `submit`) - change to `<button type='button' `

Comment: if it is anchor tag, just put "#" inside href="#", it will also stop your page to reload

Comment: Thanks, guys. Using the hashtag in href worked.

Comment: @Zak That's not a hashtag, it's a hash.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use hide event to make refresh.

```
$('#modal_close').on('hide', function() {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But apparently it works if I put a # in anchor tag of modal_close div.